# SQL:How return record by look up max assign column?

Tags: sql, db2

data soure:

```
id  data1   data2
1   1       4
2   1       5
3   2       6
4   2       7
```

I need find data2 max and same data1. I hope return:

```
data1   id  data2
1       2   5
2       4   7
```

I try to: `select data1, id, max(data2) from table1 group by data1, id`.
But it false.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Answer (score 0):

Most databases including DB2 support the ANSI standard window functions.  So a typical approach is simply:

```
select id, data1, data2
from (select id, data1, data2, max(data2) over (partition by data1) as max_data2
      from t
     ) t
where data2 = max_data2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select  data1, id, data2
    from table1 t
where data2 = (select max(data2) from table1 where data1 = t.data1)
order by data1
```